# asprintf overwriting memory for realloc

Tags: c, printf, realloc

I have the following code that does not work when using both `asprintf` and `realloc`.

The error I am getting is:

```
*** glibc detected *** a.out: realloc(): invalid old size: 0x006f1430 ***
```

Based on what I have researched it looks like when I use `asprintf` it is overwriting some memory that `realloc` uses.  This doesn't make sense to me since `asprintf` is supposed to be safe and dynamically allocate using the appropriate string length.  Not using `asprintf` causes the program to run fine, but I need the functionality of `asprintf` for my project.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
  int ifCount = 1;
  int stringCount = 1;
  char** IFs = NULL;

  //Broken code
  char* message;
  asprintf(&message, "Hello: %d", stringCount);

  //Working code, but not the alternative I want to take
  //char* message = "Hello";

  IFs = (char**) realloc(IFs, sizeof(char*) * ifCount);
  IFs[ifCount - 1] = (char*) realloc(IFs[ifCount - 1], sizeof(char) * strlen(message));
  strcpy(IFs[ifCount - 1], message);

  printf("Message: %s\n", message);
  printf("Copy: %s\n", IFs[ifCount - 1]);
  free(message);
}
```

Comment: Don't change the name of your post to include `(answered)` on your question when it's been solved here. Just click the check mark by the answer that solves your problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
IFs[ifCount - 1] = (char*) realloc(IFs[ifCount - 1], sizeof(char) * strlen(message));
```

is passing a non-initialized pointer to `realloc()`, which is the cause of the error.

Also:

1. Remember that strings need termination space, the above is allocating `strlen(message)` characters which is 1 too few. This will cause `strcpy()` to do a buffer overrun when copying.
2. Please remember that `realloc()`, like all functions that allocate heap memory, can fail. This is true for `asprintf()` too.
3. [Don't cast the return value of `realloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).
4. Avoid `sizeof (char)`, since it's always 1 it adds very little value to the code.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `realloc` with a `NULL` or uninitialized first argument, just use `malloc` to begin with.

If the `realloc` call is necessary in the `IFs[ifCount - 1] = (char*) realloc(...)` call, then on the previous line, use `calloc` instead - that will at least zero out the allocated memory so that `realloc` is given a proper `NULL` pointer.

Comment: No, using `calloc()`, which initializes to all-bits-zero, is not valid for pointers. There's no guarantee that all-bits-zero is the proper in-memory pattern for a `NULL` pointer.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - appreciated.